# The resource name is not a valid identifier for devexpress gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, resources, devexpress

I want to translate `DevExpress GridView` filter text from English to Persian.
I added a `.resx` file into asp.net project and fill it.
But I have some problem.

1. The resource name `ASPxGridViewStringId.GroupPanel` is not a valid identifier.
2. After added this `.resx` file, and run project, not happen any thing.

How can I fix this problem?
[image: Grid]
[image: Resource]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK!!!! I do it, according to the similar question in this page, I added two ".resx" into App_GlobalResources folder.
one of them is default lang "English" and other is target lang "Persian".

```
DevExpress_Web_ASPxGridView_v15_1.rexs = default
DevExpress_Web_ASPxGridView_v15_1.Fa.resx = target
```

and translate it's values to persian.
finally change `"UICULTURE"` to `"fa-ir"`.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" UICulture="fa-ir" %>
```

[image]
Thanks God :)  .
 i put this answer in [Devexpress](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T315353#answer-3fcfcbdc-a55d-4ff7-8fd7-9e55b27639ec)

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at DevExpress Documentation topic called «[Localization](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument6909)»:

> DevExpress ASP.NET controls can be localized using one of the
>   following methods.
>
> - [Via Satellite Resource Assemblies.](https://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/CustomDocument12050.aspx)
>   This is the most universal approach, commonly used for all DevExpress products and under all
>     supported technologies.
> - [Localizing ASP.NET Controls via Localizer Objects.](https://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/CustomDocument12048.aspx)
>   This approach is appropriate if you are developing an application for a single culture
>     and you wish to translate resources into a specific language, or you
>     wish to change the default resources (for the English-US culture) to
>     their equivalents.

### Satellite Resource Assemblies

You can create your translation via [`Localization Service`](http://localization.devexpress.com/):

[image: Localization Service]

After completing the translation you can save it, download it as the assembly and add it into your project:

> To add localized resources to your application, copy satellite
>   assemblies from the unpacked archive to the corresponding subfolders
>   of your application's directory. The subfolder's name is the culture's
>   abbreviation. For example, to include German assemblies, copy the
>   folder named de from the \Bin\Framework\ directory to the Bin
>   directory of your application.

### Localizer Objects

You can create custom localizer object for your translation and use it in your application. For `GridView` your object must be derived from [`ASPxGridViewLocalizer`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/clsDevExpressWebLocalizationASPxGridViewLocalizertopic) class or from [`ASPxGridViewResLocalizer`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/clsDevExpressWebLocalizationASPxGridViewResLocalizertopic) class. In your descendant class you must ovveride `XtraLocalizer(T).GetLocalizedString` method. This method is using [`ASPxGridViewStringId`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebLocalizationASPxGridViewStringIdEnumtopic) enumeration as parameter.
Here is example:

```
public class CustomGridViewLocalizer : ASPxGridViewResLocalizer
{
    public static void Activate()
    {
        var localizer = new CustomGridViewLocalizer();
        var provider = new DefaultActiveLocalizerProvider<ASPxGridViewStringId>(localizer);
        SetActiveLocalizerProvider(provider);
    }

    public override string GetLocalizedString(ASPxGridViewStringId id)
    {
        switch (id)
        {
            case ASPxGridViewStringId.AutoFilterBeginsWith:
                return "شروع با";
            case ASPxGridViewStringId.AutoFilterContains:
                return "شامل";
            case ASPxGridViewStringId.AutoFilterDoesNotContain:
                return "شامل نمی شود";
            case ASPxGridViewStringId.AutoFilterEndsWith:
                return "به پایان می رسد با";
            case ASPxGridViewStringId.AutoFilterEquals:
                return "برابر";
            case ASPxGridViewStringId.AutoFilterNotEqual:
                return "نا برابر";
            default:
                return base.GetLocalizedString(id);
        }
    }
}
```

You need to activate this object in the `Application_Start` event handler within the `Global.asax` file:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     CustomGridViewLocalizer.Activate();
}
```